# Get country tld

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How do I programmatically get the system country tld. In the registry there's a key called sCountry which has the country's name, but in the system language, eg. If the user has the Spanish version sCountry would be Espana, German version would be Deutschland, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says that the country-code TLDs are based on [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) with [a few exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain), so presumably [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101(VS.85).aspx) with an LCTYPE of [LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373848(VS.85).aspx) would be useful for this. Oh, but you said that.

Why do you need this, anyway, if you don't mind my asking?